# will a vostro 1000 vista startup disk work on a vostro 1000 with xp?

Tags: windows-xp, dell-vostro

I was given a dell vostro 1000 with xp but the os installation was faulty so i got a new hard drive. A relative has the same computer but hers runs vista. Will her recovery disks work on my computer.

Comment: Will someone please offer a bounty? I need to fix my computer!

Comment: give it a try and see. although OEMs such as Dell frequently embed the OS activation key in the BIOS, so you may be out of luck if you don't know the key for that copy of Vista.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?  If the Vista disc still has the Recovery Console on it, you may be able to get in there to do some basic stuff.  I recall I think having some success using XP discs for 2000 or vice versa.  It will at least let you do things like run chkdsk, or roll back a Windows Update.  For any other purpose, such as reloading fresh versions of system files it will probably be much less useful.

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question